# How to resize animation in libgdx?

Tags: animation, resize, libgdx

I want to draw an animation, the size of each frame is 500x500px but when I try to resize, the animation seems to rotate...

Here the code to load frames and create animation:

Texture fireSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("fire_sheet.png"));

```
    TextureRegion[] fireFrames = new TextureRegion[4];

    fireFrames[0] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,0,0,500,500);
    fireFrames[1] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,700,0,1200,500);
    fireFrames[2] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,1450,0,1950,500);
    fireFrames[3] = new TextureRegion(fireSheet,2250,0,2750,500);


    fireAnimation = new Animation(0.5f, fireFrames);
```

In draw method I resize the animation in this way:

```
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {

        batch.enableBlending();
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        currentFrame = Assets.fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

        batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 200, 200 );

    }
```

So if I use:

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY() ); // WORKS!!! But too Big for me 500x500px
```

Instead if I use:

```
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 200, 200 ); // Animation doesn't work properly
```

What Can I do?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't tested it, but this Batch draw method has scaleX and scaleY parameters, which may resize the TextureRegion: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-

Comment: Thank You, I will try... but I want to scale to a determinate width and height in pixels... so maybe ScaleX = desideredWidth/originalwidth = 200/500 = 0,4...

Comment: Yes, exactly. "desidered/original" should give you the appropriate scale.

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work, with: currentFrame = Assets.fireAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);

            batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(),
                    currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2,
                    currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2,
                    currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),
                    currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),
                    (float)getWidth()/(float)currentFrame.getRegionWidth(),
                    (float)getHeight()/(float)currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),
                    getRotation()
            );

Comment: The animation seems to rotate, not the desired effect

Comment: Try this as a test (assuming 500 is your original TextureRegion size):
batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 0, 0, 500, 500, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0);

Comment: Thanks I have solved with your test, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a test (assuming 500 is your original TextureRegion size): batch.draw(currentFrame, getX(), getY(), 0, 0, 500, 500, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0);

Thaks to Tekkerue